# WebAPI route message handler from other route gets called

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, owin, katana

I'm currently using WebAPI running on OWIN/Katana. I've defined two message handlers:

- `CorsHandler`: Allowing CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing), will be applied on all HTTP messages
- `HmacAuthenticationHandler`: Checks if the user is authenticated, will only be applied on routes which needs authentication.

My `HttpConfiguration` will be configured like this:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();

/* configure routes for the web API */
// ### public routes ###
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("IndexRoute", "", new {controller = "Main", action = "get"});
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("LoginRoute", "login", new {controller = "Account", action = "Login"});
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("RegisterRoute", "register", new {controller = "Account", action = "Register"});

// ### routes that need authentication ###
// according to http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers  (last example)

// List of delegating handlers.
var handlers = new DelegatingHandler[] {
  new HmacAuthenticationHandler(controllerConfig.StorageHelper.UserLoginInfo)
};
// Create a message handler chain with an end-point.
var routeHandlers = HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(new HttpControllerDispatcher(config), handlers);

// configure route
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultRoute",
  "{controller}/{id}",
  new {id = RouteParameter.Optional},
  null,
  routeHandlers);

/* other settings (JSON formatting, ...) */

/* dependency resolver, which will pass an instance of my DAO factory to each controller */
config.DependencyResolver = new ControllerDependencyResolver(daoFactory);

/* apply CORS message handler to all messges */
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CorsHandler());
```

If I call an Web API method via AJAX call, which **needs authentication** (e.g. "127.0.0.1:80/test/id") everything work as expected. The message handler will be called as shown below:

**Valid** user credentials:

Client -> CorsHandler -> HmacAuthenticationHandler -> TestController (get(id)) -> CorsHandler -> HmacAuthenticationHandler -> Client (OK-200)

**Invalid** user credentials:

Client -> CorsHandler -> HmacAuthenticationHandler -> CorsHandler -> HmacAuthenticationHandler -> Client (Unauthorized request-403)

---

But if I call an Web API method via AJAX call, which **don't need authentication** (e.g. "127.0.0.1:80/login"). The HmacAuthenticationHandler will be called "on the way back to the client", even though it is not assigned to this route:

Client -> CorsHandler -> AccountController(login) -> CorsHandler -> **HmacAuthenticationHandler** -> Client (OK-200)

Why will the `HmacAuthenticationHandler` be called on the "public route" (during the response)? Strange thing is it'll not influence the response, client still gets OK-200.

---

**Update**

I've created a sample project and replaced all internal interfaces/implementations with fake ones, the code can be found and downloaded on BitBucket:

https://bitbucket.org/Robar/stackoverflowquestionwebapi

Comment: This should not be happening. Would it be possible for you to share a repro so that we can take a look at it?

Comment: @KiranChalla I'll try to extract the important classes and upload them somewhere like github on monday when I'm back at work.

Comment: @KiranChalla I've updated my Question with the sample code.